# Do we need to perform static and dynamic code analysis for packages that are published as unmanaged packages in salesforce?

Tags: code

Do we need to perform static and dynamic code analysis for packages that are published as unmanaged packages in salesforce? Or the salesforce platform take care of them?

Comment: I recommend using 2GP unlocked packages instead of 1GP unmanaged packages if at all possible. Note that 2GP has a 75% code coverage requirement for successful packaging and promotion.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn't automatically perform any analysis for any package, though it does perform compile and unit tests automatically for package uploads and deployments. If you want to perform a vulnerability analysis, you can do so from the [Code Scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner).